# A question about the definition of hypergeometric probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> An urn contains $n$ balls, out of which $m$ are red. We select $k$ of the balls at random, without replacement. What is the probability that $i$ of the selected balls are red?
>
> Solution: $\frac {\binom mi \binom {n - m}{k - i}}{\binom nk}$

In the numerator we have the number of all subsets with $i$ red balls and $k - i$ non-red ones. Doesn't that give the probability of choosing a red ball and then a ball of different color instead of probability of just red ball? Can someone please elaborate on this a little?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the balls as being numbered, so if you have $m$ red balls and $n$ total balls, there must be $n - m$ non-red balls, and we can number them in their respective color groups:
$$\text{Red:} \;  \{r_1, r_2, r_3, \ldots, r_m \}, \\ 
\text{Non-red:} \;   \{b_1, b_2, b_3, \ldots, b_{n-m}\}.$$  Then, when you choose $k$ balls without replacement, and you wish to count the number of ways in which $i$ of the $k$ balls are red, this means that you must also have chosen $k - i$ non-red balls, and the way to do this in each respective color group is $$\binom{m}{i} \binom{n-m}{k-i}.$$  The reason why the binomial coefficients are multiplied is that you can see, within each color group, there are different ways of selecting a subset of numbered balls in that group.

So for instance, suppose $m = 3$, $n = 7$, $k = 4$, and $i = 2$:  Then you have three red balls labeled $\{r_1, r_2, r_3\}$, four non-red balls labeled $\{b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4\}$, and you choose $4$ of these without replacement such that $2$ are red and $2$ are non-red.  Certainly, you can choose the red balls in $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ ways:  $$\{r_1, r_2\}, \{r_1, r_3\}, \{r_2, r_3\}.$$  But you are equally interested in the number of ways to choose the non-red balls, which is $\binom{4}{2} = 6$:  $$\{b_1, b_2\}, \{b_1, b_3\}, \{b_1, b_4\}, \{b_2, b_3\}, \{b_2, b_4\}, \{b_3, b_4\}.$$  Since the choice within each color group can be done independently of the choice in the other group, it follows that the total number of such choices is the product $\binom{3}{2}\binom{4}{2} = 18$, and you can enumerate them explicitly by taking one of the three labeled outcomes for red balls, and combining them with one of the six labeled outcomes for the non-red balls shown above.

The denominator is obvious and so we need not go into details about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. The urn contains total $n$ balls out of which $m$ balls are red $\Rightarrow n-m$ balls in the urn are of different color.
2. We have to select total $k$ balls from the urn containing $n$ balls.
3. Hence, the total number of outcomes that are mutually exclusive exhaustive and equally likely are = $^nC_k$.
4. We choose $i$ red balls $\Rightarrow$ we must choose $k-i$ balls that have a different color.
5. Hence, we have to choose $i$ red balls from $m$ available red balls from the urn that can be done in $^mC_i$ ways. Also, we have to choose the remaining $k$ of the balls to be selected from the balls of the other color from the urn, but there are $n-m$ of them in the urn, so can be chosen in $^{n-m}C_{k-i}$ ways.
6. Hence, total number of cases favorable to the event = $^mC_i.^{n-m}C_{k-i}$.
7. By classical definition, the probability = $\frac{^mC_i.^{n-m}C_{k-i}}{^nC_k}$.

$\begin{array}{rrrr}
\mbox{Balls} & \mbox{Total} & \mbox{Red} & \mbox{Other} \\
\mbox{In Urn} & n & m & n-m \\
\mbox{To choose} & k & i & k-i \\
\mbox{# Ways} & ^nC_k & ^mC_i & ^{n-m}C_{k-i}  
\end{array}$